# How can I get my React application to properly re-render my updated state to screen?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I call a backend endpoint on a button click and populate my useState array "searchResponse" with data from the backend call(a string result). I then want to access that data in a iframe like: searchResponse[videoCount].

I think my state is updating correctly but the screen isn't re-rendering to display the video I want at that index.

Although I must be updating the state incorrectly, as far as my understanding goes react updates the screen when a new state is set(the entire point of a framework like react no?).

`const [searchResponse, setSearchResponse] = useState([]);`

**Code to call my backend endpoint and update searchResponse**

```
async function searchYoutube() {
        try {
            let resp = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/yt/searchVideo", {
                method: "GET",
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    q: videoSearch,
                },
            });

            if (resp.ok) {
                let data = await resp.json();
                console.log("recieved value from search result: ");
                console.log(data);

                setSearchResponse((oldArray) => [...oldArray, data[0].id.videoId]); //here

                socket.emit("searchVideo", { videoId: data[0].id.videoId, room: room });
                
            } else {
                console.log("HTTP Error:", resp.status);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Fetch Error:", err);
        }
    }
```

**Here is how I define my videoId(part of youtube player):**

```
return(
  <YouTube
    ref={playerRef}
    videoId={searchResponse == undefined ? null : searchResponse[videoCount]}>

  <button onClick={searchYoutube}>click to search! </button>
);
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console? you mentioned that `I think my state is updating correctly...`, do you get an proper response from the server